# Cannot produce correct XML format using FOR XML PATH in SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am new to XML and I'm struggling to understand how to write a SQL Server stored procedure to produce a XML file from the following table.

```
Contract,ContractSection,ClaimReference,TransactionReference,ClaimReference,Ccy,PTT_Ind,PTT_Fees**
P000013-140, P000013-140_001, C000011-14, CLP00000036, C000011-14, GBP, 50, 100
P000066-888, P000066-888_001,   C000031-28, CLP00000041, C000011-14, GBP, 75, 200
```

I have tried, unsuccessfully, to use `FOR XML PATH` to produce the required format, shown here:

```
<ReportingContractEntry>
    <Contract>
        <ReinsRef>P000013-140 </ReinsRef>
    <Contract>
    <ReportingSectionEntry>
        <SectionRef>P000013-140_001 </ SectionRef >
    </ReportingSectionEntry>
    <ReportingTransactionEntry>
<ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
    <EntryReference>CLP00000036</EntryReference>
        <TechAccountAmtItem Type="ptt_ind">
            <Amt Share="reinsurer_share" Ccy="GBP">20.00</Amt>
    </TechAccountAmtItem>
        <TechAccountAmtItem Type="ptt_fees">
            <Amt Share="reinsurer_share" Ccy="GBP">590.00</Amt>
    </TechAccountAmtItem>
</ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
</ReportingTransactionEntry>
</ReportingContractEntry>
<ReportingContractEntry>
    <Contract>
        <ReinsRef>P000066-888 </ReinsRef>
    <Contract>
    <ReportingSectionEntry>
        <SectionRef>P000013-140_001 </ SectionRef >
    </ReportingSectionEntry>
    <ReportingTransactionEntry>
<ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
    <EntryReference>CLP00000041</EntryReference>
        <TechAccountAmtItem Type=" ptt_ind ">
            <Amt Share="reinsurer_share" Ccy="GBP">75.00</Amt>
    </TechAccountAmtItem>
        <TechAccountAmtItem Type="ptt_fees">
            <Amt Share="reinsurer_share" Ccy="GBP">200.00</Amt>
    </TechAccountAmtItem>
</ReportingTransactionAmountEntry>
</ReportingTransactionEntry>
</ReportingContractEntry>
```

My best efforts so far is this, but this only works with a single `TechAccountAmtItem` per `ReportingTransactionEntry`. And I need to add multiple `TechAccountAmtItems`

```
SELECT  
   RTRIM(policyRef) AS 'Contract/ReinsRef',
   RTRIM(policyRef) + '_001' AS 'ReportingSectionEntry/SectionRef',
   RTRIM(TransactionReference) AS 'ReportingTransactionEntry/ReportingTransactionAmountEntry/EntryReference' ,
   'ptt_ind' AS 'ReportingTransactionEntry/ReportingTransactionAmountEntry/TechAccountAmtItem/@Type',
   'reinsurer_share' AS 'ReportingTransactionEntry/ReportingTransactionAmountEntry/TechAccountAmtItem/Amt/@Share'  ,
   CASE WHEN currency_id = 26 THEN 'GBP' ELSE 'EUR' END AS 'ReportingTransactionEntry/ReportingTransactionAmountEntry/TechAccountAmtItem/Amt/@Ccy'  ,
   SUM(Paid_This_Time_Indemnity) AS 'ReportingTransactionEntry/ReportingTransactionAmountEntry/TechAccountAmtItem/Amt'
   --,SUM(Paid_This_Time_Fees) -- I can't figure out how to get a second <TechAmountItem> within the same <ReportingTransactionAmountEntry> ???????
FROM 
    #tmpClm2
GROUP BY
    policyRef, ClaimReference, TransactionReference, ClaimReference, currency_id
FOR XML PATH ('ReportingContractEntry')
```

As I said, XML is completely new to me so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not even sure if using FOR XML PATH is the right way to go about this.

It did appear to be the easiest and most flexible option available.

Comment: You have two columns named "ClaimReference" in your schema.  I don't see how this could work.

Comment: Also, you reference `policyRef` but this column doesn't show up in your schema.  Probably a good idea to clean this up to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema in your example doesn't correspond with your query, but the problem is pretty straightforward.  In your query, you can use a subquery where you want multiple elements returned.

Instead of:

```
   'ptt_ind' AS 'ReportingTransactionEntry/ReportingTransactionAmountEntry/TechAccountAmtItem/@Type',
    'reinsurer_share' AS 'ReportingTransactionEntry/ReportingTransactionAmountEntry/TechAccountAmtItem/Amt/@Share'  ,
    CASE WHEN currency_id = 26 THEN 'GBP' ELSE 'EUR' END AS 'ReportingTransactionEntry/ReportingTransactionAmountEntry/TechAccountAmtItem/Amt/@Ccy'  ,
    SUM(Paid_This_Time_Indemnity) AS 'ReportingTransactionEntry/ReportingTransactionAmountEntry/TechAccountAmtItem/Amt'
```

Try:

```
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT
        'ptt_ind' AS 'TechAccountAmtItem/@Type',
        'reinsurer_share' AS 'TechAccountAmtItem/Amt/@Share'  ,
        CASE WHEN currency_id = 26 THEN 'GBP' ELSE 'EUR' END AS 'TechAccountAmtItem/Amt/@Ccy'  ,
        SUM(Paid_This_Time_Indemnity) AS 'TechAccountAmtItem/Amt'
        UNION
        SELECT
        'ptt_fees' AS 'TechAccountAmtItem/@Type',
        'reinsurer_share' AS 'TechAccountAmtItem/Amt/@Share'  ,
        CASE WHEN currency_id = 26 THEN 'GBP' ELSE 'EUR' END AS 'TechAccountAmtItem/Amt/@Ccy'  ,
        SUM(Paid_This_Time_Fees) AS 'TechAccountAmtItem/Amt'
    ) iq FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
) AS 'ReportingTransactionEntry/ReportingTransactionAmountEntry'
```

Comment: Thanks for seeing past my poorly formatted example and seeing the problem. The subquery fixed it. Many thanks